# jQuery on scroll event not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, scroll

I have an application with a lot ajax actions going on. So pretty much all my events are handled like this:

```
jQuery( 'body' ).on( 'click', '#id', function ( event ) {

    // Do something

});
```

instead of:

```
jQuery( '#id' ).click( function() {

   // Do something

});
```

This works with all events pretty well except the scroll event like this doesn't work:

```
jQuery( 'body' ).on( 'scroll', '#id', function ( event ) {

    // Do something

});
```

With the mousewheel event it works great. Is there anything wrong or is there no scroll event?

Comment: You should at least be aware that delegating all events up to the body isn't very good practice, and should generally be avoided if you have other options or static parent elements that can be used instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the `scroll` event does not bubble up the DOM, so delegation with `live()`, `on()` or `delegate()` won't work.

You will have to bind the event handler to the dynamically-created element yourself.

[**Reference**](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/scroll.html)

Comment: This seems like a not too great solution. But probably its the only thing that is doable ... it would probably also be possible to sync the event handler after each ajax call but my code is several thousand lines big soo ...

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this helps

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
   $("#head").html($(this).scrollTop());
});
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/frippa/nLa7a2p3/2/)

Comment: Absolutely not but thanks. Your solution is the standard jquery way for the scroll event but you cannot bind this to elements that aren't in the dom on runtime. So for all stuff that is created dynamically this solution is useless unless you put it into the ajax respond itself (thats exactly what BenM suggested).

Answer (score 0):

To be able to fire a scroll event of a DOM element, you should put this in your css:

```css
selector { overflow-y: scroll }
```